# Simple key generation with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a file with words line by line as follows:

```
plane
car
motorbike
truck
boat
...
```

I am trying to write a Scala program that reads the values from the file, and maps each word to a (key, value) pair, where the key is going to be an integer that increments with each value. I've written the following:

```
val vocabFile = sc.textFile("file:///vocab.txt")
val vocabIndex=0;
val vocabs = vocabFile.map(x => (vocabIndex+=1, x))
```

But I get the following error:

```
<console>:31: error: value += is not a member of Int
     val vocabs = vocabularyFile.map(x => (vocabIndex+=1, x))
```

The expected output would be something like this:

```
(1, plane)
(2, car)
(3, motorbike)
(4, truck)
(5, boat)
....
```

Is there any way to generate such pairs directly without a loop?

Comment: Your requirement seems not appropriate in distributed cluster mode. As RDDs are distributed in nature, your data would be partitioned (which will not give you actual index of each word in file) and if you don't partition then the process won't be efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .zipWithIndex() function on RDDs.

Example:

```
val input = List("Boat", "Car")
sc.parallelize(input).zipWithIndex().map(_.swap)
```

Result:

```
(0,Boat)
(1,Car)
```

I would not recommend to use a shared variable as index, because it is expensive to keep it up to date across the cluster.

Comment: Good one! I would just complete the code as `vocabFile.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)`...

Comment: This works very nicely! But is there anyway to start the indexes from 1? I need to do a join with another RDD and it starts its indexes from 1. If not, I can just always map adding one to each index, but would be nice to have it instantly.

Comment: @alejandrogiron I'm afraid it always starts with 0, because RDDs are zero-indexed like all other ordered scala collections.

Comment: That's fine, I'll do the mapping then, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to reassign the new value to `vocabIndex`, so it should be a `var`:

```
var vocabIndex = 0;
```

Also, assignments in Scala result in `Unit`, not in the value being assigned (like in Java). So you need to break your code into:

```
vocabFile.map(x => { val e = (vocabIndex, x); vocabIndex += 1; e })
```

**EDIT:** As your `vocabFile` is a Spark `RDD`, you'll get all the parallelism issues with `vocabIndex`. I recommend @SteffenSchmitz 's solution instead.

Comment: I'm getting repeated values for some reason? `Array[(Int, String)] = Array((0,Plane), (1,Car), (2,Motorbike), (0,Truck), (1,Boat))`

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use .zipWithIndex() after use scala distinct to be sure that there are none element repeated:

For instance:

```
val text = Seq(plane,car,car)
val result = text.distinct.zipWithIndex
res0: Seq[(String, Int)] = List((plane,0), (car,1))
```